# How do I register a WFC host factory in a MORYX module?

Tags: c#, moryx

The [ProductManagement](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-AbstractionLayer/blob/9275ce1381e01ecedadde21ef35d994145b6ec94/src/Moryx.Products.Management/ModuleController/ModuleController.cs#L47) and [ResourceManagement](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-AbstractionLayer/blob/9275ce1381e01ecedadde21ef35d994145b6ec94/src/Moryx.Resources.Management/ModuleController/ModuleController.cs#L58) use the following command to do that

```cs
Container.RegisterWcf(WcfHostFactory);
```

But when I try to do that in my custom module, I get the following error message:

> CS1061 'IContainer' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterWcf' and no accessible extension method 'RegisterWcf' accepting a first argument of type 'IContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing an assembly reference? And if that's the case: Which one am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In preparation for cross-platform we extracted WCF to an isolated package *Moryx.Runtime.Wcf*. That also contains the container extension.